# Cómo animar un div?

Tags: javascript

***Intenté hacer un ciclo for, en el cual cada iteración le aumentara su escala:***

```js
var about = document.getElementById("about");

about.addEventListener("mouseover",b08);
about.addEventListener("mouseover",animar);
about.addEventListener("mouseleave",b02);



function b08(){
  about.style.opacity = "0.8";
}
function b02(){
  about.style.opacity = "0.2";
}

function animar(){
  for(let j=0.01;j<0.08;j+=0.01){
    setTimeout(function(){
    about.style.transform = "scale(1"+j+")";
      console.log(j);
    },200);
  }
}
```

```css
#about{
background-color:dimgray;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:50px;
position:absolute;
top:40%;
left:40%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="about"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Pero no me funcionó,ya que lo que quiero obtener es que al colocar el mouse por encima el div **crezca un poco su tamaño**, simplemente eso, como funcionaría en `css3`, ***pero*** con `js`, además por favor, me gustaría que me dijeran cual es mi error y **como debería hacerse*** **SIN JQUERY**

Comment: ¿Hay alguna razón para hacerlo en javascript en lugar de CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Recomiendo hacerlo únicamente con CSS, pero si quieres hacerlo con javascript aqui la respuesta.

Css vas a terminar usando si o si, lo edites con JQuery o Javascript.
Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de cambiar el tamaño.

Si quieres ponerlo mas lento solo es necesario aplicarle temporizadores.

```js
function crecer(){
    var circulo = document.getElementById("circulo");
    circulo.style.height="150px";
    circulo.style.width="150px";
};

function pequeno(){
    var circulo = document.getElementById("circulo");
    circulo.style.height="100px";
    circulo.style.width="100px";
};
```

```css
.circleBase {
    border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
}

.type1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="circulo" onmouseover="crecer()" onmouseout="pequeno()" class="circleBase type1"></div>
```

---

### ## EDITATO ## *con animaciones*

```js
function crecer(altura){
  var elem = document.getElementById("circulo");   
  elem.onmouseover=null;
  elem.onmouseout=function(){cancelar_grande();};
  var height = parseInt(altura);;
  window.id = setInterval(crecer_raton, 5);
  function crecer_raton() {
    if (height == 350) {
      clearInterval(window.id);
      elem.onmouseout= function(){pequeno(height);};
      elem.onmouseover= function(){cancelar_peque();};
    } else {
      height++; 
      elem.style.height = height + 'px'; 
      elem.style.width = height + 'px'; 
    }
  }
};

function pequeno(altura){
  var elem = document.getElementById("circulo"); 
  elem.onmouseout=null;
  elem.onmouseover=function(){cancelar_peque();};
  var height =  parseInt(altura);
  window.id = setInterval(crecer_raton, 5);
  function crecer_raton() {
    if (height == 100) {
      clearInterval(window.id);
      elem.onmouseover=function(){crecer(100);};
      elem.onmouseout=function(){cancelar_grande();};
    } else {
      height--; 
      elem.style.height = height + 'px'; 
      elem.style.width = height + 'px'; 
    }
  }
};

function cancelar_grande(){
  window.clearInterval(window.id);
  var elem = document.getElementById("circulo"); 
  var height = elem.style.height; 
  pequeno(height);
}

function cancelar_peque(){
  window.clearInterval(window.id);
  var elem = document.getElementById("circulo"); 
  var height = elem.style.height; 
  crecer(height);
}
```

```css
.circleBase {
    border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
}

.type1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="circulo" onmouseover="crecer(100)" class="circleBase type1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo el motivo de que el resto de respuestas empleen JS..

Esta es mi respuesta solo con CSS:

```css
.circleBase {
            border-radius: 50%;
            behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
            transition: all 1s;
            -webkit-transition: all 1s;
        }
    
        .type1 {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: yellow;
            border: 3px solid red;
        }
        .circleBase:hover {
            transform: scale(2);
            -webkit-transform: scale(2);
        }
```

```html
<div id="circulo" class="circleBase type1"></div>
```

Comment: Porque el SO ha pedido hacerlo con JS... Sino lo logico es lo que has puesto.

Answer (score 0):

***Ya que nadie me respondió como necesitaba, asi lo solucioné:***

```js
var about = document.getElementById("about");

about.addEventListener("mouseover",b08);
about.addEventListener("mouseover",animar);
about.addEventListener("mouseleave",b02);



function b08(){
  about.style.opacity = "0.8";
}
function b02(){
  about.style.opacity = "0.2";
}

function animar(){
  about.style.transform = "scale(1.6)";
  about.style.transition = "all 2s";
}
```

```css
#about{
background-color:dimgray;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:50px;
position:absolute;
top:40%;
left:40%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="about"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creo que las respuestas si tienen lo que tu necesitas. En ningun momento has especificado que luego permanezca en ese tamaño y cambie el color. Solo has pedido que aumente. "colocar el mouse por encima el div crezca un poco su tamaño, simplemente eso".

Comment: Ninguna respuesta me lo explico, yo  vengo a aprender no a copiar códigos

Comment: No veo que en la tuya estes explicando nada Eduardo. Creo mas adecuada la respuesta de Daniel a tu pregunta y en caso de necesitar obligatoriamente javascript puro, la mia. Creo que la dada por ti se sale de lo pedido y no cumple con lo exigido en la pregunta.

Comment: Ilógico que se salga de lo que necesita la pregunta, si yo fúi el que fabricó la respuestas en mis necesidades, en la mía no hay practicamente nada que explicar, la tuya es larga y confusa cosa que debería traer una explicación y la de daniel es css y yo nunca etiqueté css